# Encrypted User defined functon is visible by right click and script Function as, but the definition is null while querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, user-defined-functions

I could see the function definition on right click and create a script, but
when I try to view by querying, the definition seems to be null, only for the encrypted functions. How could I get the definition of query result?

Comment: If it is encrypted u can not get from the query result, it is worth of checking through select *  from sys.database_permissions

Comment: Ok. Thank you @BHouse